# Change implementation of ninject dependency after singleton instantiation

Tags: ninject, mvvm-light, xamarin.forms

So, I have a viewmodel class in a xamarin project that I inject some dependencies into via ninject binding on app start. One of these is an IDialogService.

When my MainPage in my application changes it raises a property changed event and I rebind the implementation of the dialog service since it is tied to the MainPage.

If my viewmodel has already been created with lets say DialogServiceA and then when MainPage changes we rebind to DialogServiceB, will my viewmodel be using service A or B? I think it is using A and therefore does not display in the UI because it is tied to a MainPage that no longer exists.

So, if this is the case how can I dynamically change my dialog service but then update classes that have already been instantiated without changing everything to get the current dialog service from the container every time its used (therefore not injecting it at all really, and doing more of a servicelocator)

Also, if this approach is completely wrong, set me straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. Re-configuration of the container does not affect already instanciated objects.

If you want to change dependencies without re-instanciating the dependent (parent ViewModel) there's a few possibilities for you:

- use a factory to instanciate the service every time. Implement an [Abstract Factory (Site by Mark Seeman)](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) or use [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory) to do so
- instead of injecting a service directly, inject an adapter. The adapter then redirects the request to the currently appropriate service. To do so, either all service can be injected into the adapter, or you can use a factory as with the possibility above.
- instead of inject a service directly, inject a proxy. The proxy is quite similar to the adapter, but instead of coding every method / property redirection specifically, you code a generic redirect by an interceptor. Here's a [tutorial on castle dynamic proxy](http://kozmic.net/dynamic-proxy-tutorial/)

At the end of the day, however, i believe you'll also need a way to manage when to change the service / which it should be. There's probably a design alternative which doesn't rely on exchanging objects in such a manner.. which would make it an easier (and thus better?) design.

Edit: i just saw that you also tagged the question as xamarin-forms. In that case it most likely won't be an option to use either a dynamic proxy nor ninject.extensions.factory (it relies on dynamic proxies, too). Why? dynamic proxy / IL emitting is not supported on all platforms, AFAIR specifically on Apple devices this can't be done.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing the "thin adapter" idea from Mark Seeman. It works perfectly now.